# Check if a list contains any value from a vector in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I want to create a binary column that shows whether another column, which is a list of characters, contains any value from a vector.

Specifically, I want to create a column that says whether one has experienced their manager leaving a company in the past year. For this, I have a `all_manager` column that is a list of all managers one had in the last year. And then, I have a `terminated_managers` vector that has all names of managers who have terminated in the past year.

```
df$all_manager

[[1]]
[1] John Mary

[[2]]
[1] Paul John

[[3]]
[1] Mary Tom Lilly

terminated_managers <- c("Mary", "Bill")
```

And I want to create `manager_termed_yn` column such that:

```
df$manager_termed_yn

[1]TRUE
[2]FALSE
[3]TRUE
```

I'll appreciate your help! First time posting, so apologies that the example is not the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_manager <- list(c("John", "Mary"), c("Paul", "John"), c("Mary", "Tom", "Lilly"))
terminated_managers <- c("Mary", "Bill")
```

We can use

```
colSums(sapply(all_manager, "%in%", x = terminated_managers)) > 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: That's such an easy and clean solution. Thank you!

Comment: @FionaLee Thanks. You are more than welcomed to vote up my answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

Let list `l` as

```
l <- list("John Mary","Paul John", "Mary Tom Lilly")
l

[[1]]
[1] "John Mary"

[[2]]
[1] "Paul John"

[[3]]
[1] "Mary Tom Lilly"
```

Then

```
sapply(l, function(x) {sum(match(str_split(x, " ", simplify = T), terminated_managers), na.rm = T) == 1}, simplify = T)

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create some example data to work with that looks similar to your own.

```r
# Example data 
set.seed(123)
data <- replicate(5, list(paste0(sample(letters, size = 5, replace = T), collapse = "")))
data
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "osncj"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "rvket"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "nvyze"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "syyic"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "hzgji"

# Example vector
vec <- c("osn", "rvket", "foo")
```

Your data are currently stored as a list. From the looks of it, each element of the list has 1 name in it stored as a character `vector`. My guess about this is because for every row of the output you showed that starts with DOUBLE brackets (e.g. `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, etc.), there is only one row below it that starts with single brackets (and the index of those are always `[1]`).

```r
class(data)
#> [1] "list"
```

Given you have this data structure, you can convert this into a vector:

```r
df2vec <- unlist(data)
df2vec
#> [1] "osncj" "rvket" "nvyze" "syyic" "hzgji"
```

We can determine if the values in df2vec exactly match values in vec:

```r
df2vec %in% vec
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And here are the values that appear in both:

```r
df2vec[df2vec %in% vec]
#> [1] "rvket"
```

If we want to look for partial matches instead that would, for example, return `TRUE` when matching `"Rob"` to `"Robert Frost"`, we need substring pattern matching:

```r
partials <- grepl(df2vec, pattern = paste(vec, collapse = "|"))

partials
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

df2vec[partials]
#> [1] "osncj" "rvket"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(manager_termed_yn = any(unlist(all_manager) %in% terminated_managers))
```

**Output**

```
  id      all_manager manager_termed_yn
1  1       John, Mary              TRUE
2  2       Paul, John             FALSE
3  3 Mary, Tom, Lilly              TRUE
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, all_manager = list(c("John", "Mary"), 
    c("Paul", "John"), c("Mary", "Tom", "Lilly"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

terminated_managers <- c("Mary", "Bill")
```